# Spring-boot remove actuator request from metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot, grafana, metrics, prometheus

By using spring-boot i am exposing some actuator:
*health, info, prometheus, metrics, shutdown.*
Then the monitoring is delegated to grafana.

I would like to don't make that the metrics registers actuator's calls. I would like that the monitoring would be only for my exposed API REST.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please reframe the question once because we are not getting what exactly you want.

Comment: Actually grafana registers also the call made to the actuators, and i would like to don't register this calls